# How to describe this model

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, paired-comparisons

I have a study where subjects have received treatment to one eye, the other eye is untreated and is acting as a control. There are 3 measures (of retinal thickness) taken in each eye.

The model I am using is:

```
fit <- lmer(Thickness~tx + Region + (1|ID) + (1|ID:Eye), data)
```

Where `tx` is treated / untreated and `Region` is the repeated measure.

I need a sentence to describe this for publication!

My current attempt looks like this:

> Changes of retinal thickness between treated and untreated eyes was examined using a linear mixed effects model[6]. Each subject was considered to have an independent intercept and the three regions within each eye were treated as repeated measures.

Is this correct, could it be better?

Comment: What does `Eye` mean ?  right or left ?